# How to get Text to follow semicircular path, read left to right and oriented counterclockwise

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, text, path

[image: do not want it like this]

I'm using adobe illustrator, and I'm trying to get the text to orient from left to right(counterclockwise) and not upside down but I cannot get it to do that on the path I've created. Im pretty beginner with illustrator, any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 4):

1. Select selection tool, black arrow, <kbd>V</kbd>
2. Click on the line (handle) in the middle of the text and drag it upwards.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Type > Type on a Path > Type on a path options`

[image]

Tick the `Flip` box.

[image]

Depending on what version of Illustrator you are using, dragging the I-beam across the path can be troublesome. The flip box does it easily and without the jerky, uncontrollable, dragging which can occur at times. But dragging, as cockypop suggest, does work as well.